# What kind of video card do I need to play BluRay disks?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, blu-ray, high-definition, desktop-computer

I got a BluRay drive for my desktop PC that is hooked up to my Sony Bravia TV using VGA, however using PowerDVD or WinDVD (actually WinDVD just dies) it says my onboard video card is incompatible and it wont play disks the drive seems to read just fine.

Is there a cheap video card I can pick up that will run BluRay disks? Is there some specific card technology that is necessary, or is it just a card that offers DVI/HDMI outs?

If it helps, [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16827151222) is the BluRay drive I have (It has the 04 firmware installed):

**Edit**

Going to try and [pick up a new video card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=14-127-596&SortField=0&SummaryType=0&Pagesize=10&PurchaseMark=&SelectedRating=5&VideoOnlyMark=False&VendorMark=&IsFeedbackTab=true&Keywords=%28keywords%29#scrollFullInfo).

For $30, free shipping, and a $10 mail in rebate it seems like a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably [Protected Media Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_Media_Path) that is stopping the VGA (analog output).  You'll need a video card with an HDMI or DVI output that supports [HDCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection).  Any card made in the past couple of years should support that.

Comment: Yet another reason for not using Windows.

Comment: Cute. I'm going to try and pick up a new card and see if that works.

Comment: Card worked out great, thanks! BTW m0skit0, I believe HDCP is on Mac's too, it's just more seamless since you can't really build your own rig.